# How can I reverse the bits of an unsigned byte in Perl?

Tags: perl

For example, the number 178 should convert to the letter "M".

178 is 10110010.

Reversing all of the bits should give 01001101, which is 77 or "M" as a character.
I taught about using the Reverse function but I don't know how can I use it on an @array.

```
use strict;
use warnings 'all';

    open(my $fh1, '<', 'sym.dat') or die $!;
    open(my $fh2, '<', 'sym2.txt') or die $!;
    open my $fh_out, '>', 'symout.txt' or die $!;

    until ( eof $fh1 or eof $fh2 ) {

        my @l1 = map hex, split '', <$fh1>;
        my @l2 = map hex, split '', <$fh2>;
        my $n = @l2 > @l1 ? @l2 : @l1;

        my @sum = map {
            no warnings 'uninitialized';
        $l1[$_] + $l2[$_];
    } 0 .. $n-1;
        @sum = map { split //, sprintf '%08X', $_ } @sum;
        print { $fh_out } "reverse @sum\n";
    }
```

I am calculating here the sum of hex values but the question is the same I want to reverse the byte values.

Comment: Add the code to your question

Comment: print { $fh_out } "reverse @sum\n"; "fh_out is an output file that outputs hex sum from 2 files"

Comment: IMO your question has a misleading title. You're not trying to invert bits. Inverting bits is generally understood to mean flipping their values, i.e. ones become zeroes and zeroes turn into ones.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You call `reverse()` on an array, by just passing the array to the function. However, like all Perl functions, you can't put a function call inside a string. So instead of

```
print { $fh_out } "reverse @sum\n";
```

You want:

```
print { $fh_out } reverse(@sum), "\n";
```

The parentheses around `@sum` are required here to prevent the newline from being included in the arguments to `reverse`.

Answer (score 1):

This inverses the bits:

```
>perl -E"say pack 'C', ~178 & 0xFF"
M
```

This reverses the bits:

```
>perl -E"say pack 'B8', unpack 'b8', pack 'C', 178"
M
```

This reverses the bits:

```
>perl -E"say pack 'b8', sprintf '%08b', 178"
M
```

Comment: Thank you a lot for the clarification, may I ask a n00b question? and sorry for doing it here but I got no questions left in the question section. How can I force perl to read from the two files every 8 bits as 1 hex value, because in this case it reads every bit as a hex value. Thank you in advance :)

Comment: "reading 8 bits as 1 hex value" makes no sense (hex is a string representation of a number), so I don't understand the question.

Comment: If you have file 1: 00 00 00 0f ; file 2: 00 00 00 0f the output sum will be: 00 00 00 01e instead of "00 00 00 1e"

Comment: I presume `00 00 00 0f` refers to four bytes. Not sure which of those outputs you want. If you want the first: `my $four_bytes = pack('N', unpack('N', $four_bytes_from_file1) + unpack('N', $four_bytes_from_file2) )`. If you want the second: `my $hex = sprintf("%08x", unpack('N', $four_bytes_from_file1) + unpack('N', $four_bytes_from_file2) ); $hex =~ s/..\K/ /sg;` // You can read 4 bytes using `read($fh, my $buf, 4)`.

Answer (score 0):

Shortest I can come up with for inverting is `~pack "C", 178` (eta: but your title and your text are quite confusing as to whether you want to flip the bits or reverse them, your bit-pattern has the same result for both but this is not generally the same). In the latter case one could do `pack "B8", scalar reverse unpack "B8", pack "C", 178`, just don't forget to add a comment to that ;-).

Comment: Can I ask what the difference between flip the bits and reverse them?

Comment: Flipping the bits means converting all zeros to ones and all ones to zero. So 11111100 becomes 00000011. Reversing the bits means reversing the order. So 11111100 becomes 00111111. Your code is reversing the bits. But you ask for help inverting the bits. Inverting is another word for flipping.

Comment: thank you for explaining that for me , I wanted to reverse the order so It's ok :)